# Split Model declaration among several app in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I am working and building my website with Django and I am facing this logical issue.

My project is made by several app.

I would like to declare in each one of these a "piece" of a bigger model that will be represented in one single table-
Example:

- *model Person*
- *model DetailsPerson*

As each single app specifies a specific part of the person, my idea was to decentralize the declaration of *DetailsPerson* model so that they figure in one single table but each app enlarge the fields the app needs to work.

Is this possible?

---

- **EDIT 25/11/2021**: here is a graphical representation of how I would like my models be working like

[image: 1]

I would like to declaire, "to detail" the table Person adding in various app the fields the app itself introduce. In this way I can have a single table with various fields, introduced time by time as I create new apps into my project.
Is this possible? My aim is to keep only one table.

I tried with Nechoj's first solution but declairing *Person(models.Model)* and then in another app *PsysicalModel(Person)* adding *field_1* and *field_2* and then *makemigrations* and *migrate* doesn't fill my table with field_1 and field_2 but leaves the table with only *id_person, birthdate and city*.

Answer (score 0):

#### Class Inheritance

You can use class inheritance, like

```
class Person(models.Model):
    (fields)

# in other file, import this class an inherit
class PersonWithDetails(Person):
    (add. fields)
```

**EDIT**: According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) on `multitable inheritance` this will create an additional table for `PersonWithDetails` that holds the additional fields. However, to the user it appears as if all data is stored in a single table. For example, `filter`and `update` queries work as expected:

```
PersonWithDetails.objects.filter(<some criteria>)
```

will return instances that contain all fields (both from Person and PersonWithDetails) as if all fields where stored in a single table PersonWithDetails. Furthermore, it is possible to select all persons irrespective of their details:

```
Person.objects.all()
```

will return all Person instances, including those that have been created as PersonWithDetails. If you have a Person instance `p` at hand, then you can check whether a special attribute is present and then know, whether this instance is also a PersonWithDetails:

```
if p.personwithdetails is not None:
    p.personwithdetails.field_1
```

This example show how to acces fields of the PersinWithDetails if the instance at hand is Person.

#### OneToOneField

Another option is to use `one-to-one` relations.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    (fields)

# in other file, import this class and do 
class DetailsPerson(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    (additional fields)
```

In case of adding details to a Person class, I would prefer the second option.

#### ForeignKey

And if you want to have several different Detail classes to one Person, use ForeignKey:

```
class DetailsPerson1(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    (additional fields)

class DetailsPerson2(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    (additional fields)
```

Comment: I thought about the second solution *but* in such a way I will have several mysql table, one table for each model. My goal was, instead, get one several models from several apps but groups all of them in one single mysql table. The first solution I need to try whether it creates a second mysql table or not

Comment: Inheritance will not create several tables for the base class. PersonWithDetails will be a Person as well und you can retrieve all persons from the database with `Person.objects.all()` which will give you also the inherited object instances. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Comment: Can't get your first solution working (that loooks to me the optimal as it doesn't create further tables but keep everything compact). Once _DetailsPerson(Person)_ has been declaired in a new file I lunch _makemigrations_ and _migrate_ but the table isn't fit with the new fields.

Comment: I edited my first post in order to explain better what I would like to achieve

Comment: In order to choose the best option, it is necessary to understand what kind of `queries` are required. How Django stores the information in tables is not really relevant to this question, whether it is one or two tables. In the first option (inheritance) there is one table for Person and other tables for PersonWith Details, but inside the queries it appears as if it was organized in one table.

Comment: Indeed my aim is to build a single table from different models spared among various app so that logically everything is connected. Most of the queries I will be working with are _UPDATE_ or simple _filter().values("field_1")_

Comment: Added some edits to clarify the table structure of the inheritance option